# Formula relating sum of values of a function to its integral

Tags: soft-question, terminology, mathematics, integration

[image]

I came across the above formula in some quantum mechanics lecture notes explaining the Casimir effect. Anyone seen it before if so could you please tell me its 'name'. B refers to the Bernoulli numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's called [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).